# Reset MetisMenu after loading data asynchronously

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, metismenu

I am using [MetisMenu](https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu) with a dynamic `<div>`. When I load a new submenu under this `<div>`, the plugin stops functioning.

Is there any way to reset the plugin in the success part of my AJAX call?
I've tried:

```
$('#menu').metisMenu({
   toggle: false // disable the auto collapse. Default: true.
});
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML and JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

[MetisMenu](https://github.com/onokumus/metismenu/) could not be called more than once because it calls `init()` function only once in its lifetime.

So it means if you are loading content of a element `<div id="menu">` asynchronously using ajax and after that again binding event to `<div id="menu">` by `$('#menu').metisMenu();` won't make any difference.

So what you have to do is firstly destroy the existing metismenu event handler and then create a new one like below:

```
$('#menu').metisMenu('dispose'); //to stop and destroy metisMenu
$('#menu').metisMenu();
```

Below code is in angularjs

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('menuCtrl', menuCtrl);

menuCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function menuCtrl($scope, $http) {
  var url = "http://localhost/api/menus";

  $http.post(url)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

      // Destroy the existing metisMenu
      angular.element("#menu").metisMenu('dispose');

      //---- Update You div with data -----//

      // Create new binding
      angular.element("#menu").metisMenu();
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Error");
    });
}
```

Comment: when i use $('#menu').metisMenu('dispose'); get the "Uncaught TypeError: this.dispose is not a function" error

Comment: @kscius, which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
$('#menu').metisMenu()
```

should be sufficient to make MetisMenu aware of any new list elements that you have added via an AJAX call.

Make sure that you have added the new objects as `<li>` elements under the menu's `<ul>`. Also check that you have actually updated the DOM (and not just retrieved the new objects from the server) before invoking `metisMenu`.

(Note that the `toggle` option apparently does not change the initial appearance of the menu, which will initially be collapsed and require a click to expand.)